# Is it safe to disable Temando_Shipping & Dotdigitalgroup_Email?

Tags: module, magento-2.2.5

There's a couple of Modules that are packaged with Magento Open Source these days that promote Magento Partners. I know that disabling `Magento_Signifyd` can be done safely without any collateral.

However, can `Temando_Shipping`, `Shopial_Facebook` & `Dotdigitalgroup_Email` be disabled safely without interfering with anything?

**EDIT:** 2.3.4. adds `Dotdigitalgroup_Chat`. So, both `Dotdigitalgroup` modules need to be either enabled or disabled in pairs. Otherwise this results in an Exception error when attempting to access the backend.

I've included a [source](https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-safely-remove-partner-modules/579) to an article I maintain, in case I forgot to make further edits here in the future.

Comment: With Magento 2.3.4, a new module Dotdigitalgroup_Chat is introduced. You need to disable that module if you disable the Dotdigitalgroup_Email module. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26573

Comment: Thanks, I added this information to by blog article, but didn't think to add it here. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It's absolutely safe. However, you will lose the features provided by both the extensions.

Features:

https://temando.com/en/connectors/magento-2-shipping-software
https://marketplace.magento.com/dotmailer-dotmailer-magento2-extension.html

Comment: Not really an issue. The way I see it, is that it's almost enforcing Ads on your Magento 2 installation.

Comment: Yes. Moreover, they also conflict with some custom extensions. Have Disabled both the extensions a month ago.

Comment: It does not work. Disabling does not remove the module's attributes (ts_) and they still cause issues. You will probably need to completely remove it and somehow delete it's attributes from the database

Answer (score 14):

We can use the below command to make sure the particular module has any circular dependency.

> php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules-circular

Above command generate one CSV file in **magento-root-folder/modules-circular-dependencies.csv**, please analyze this and make a decision.

Also, while disabling extension use the below command, it will throw an exception, if it has a circular dependency.

> php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module

Comment: modules-circular-dependencies.csv

Comment: @Bilal Usean where it will generate that csv. Plz let me know the path please

Comment: Got it it will save the csv file at magento2 root folder

Comment: @NagarajuK Yes it  is located in magento-root/modules-circular-dependencies.csv

Answer (score 1):

So I had a conflict between a 3rd party "FollowUp Email" extension and Temando_Shipping showing the error:

```
Missing required argument $offset of Temando\Shipping\Rest\Request\ListRequest.
```

So decided to disable Temando shipping and found this thread. 
Disabling Temando Shipping actually fixed the issue and the extension works fine now.

And well, I said let's disable all these modules that are not really used and expensive for me to try.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Temando_Shipping --clear-static-content;

php bin/magento module:disable Shopial_Facebook --clear-static-content;

php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email --clear-static-content;
```

---

Then the usual stuff:

```
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
    php bin/magento cache:clean;
    php bin/magento cache:flush;

...etc
```